# Use $base_url in a computed field?

Tags: entities, uri

Using `$base_url` to build a link in a computed field, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: base_url in eval() (line 1 of F:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\computed_field\computed_field.module(468) : eval()'d code).

Is it a way to get the site base URL in a computed field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a global scope variable and you can access it by using $GLOBALS['base_url'] instead or calling the core [base_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/7)() function to pull it into your computed field definition.

Answer (score -1):

Before using $base_url, You need to declare it just like below

`global $base_url;`

After declaring you can use
$base_url in your code.